# Can't install node with nodebrew

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I've installed nodebrew with my homebrew and attempted to install the stable version of node. I'm using Mac OSX El Capitan version 10.11.1.

```
$ nodebrew install-binary stable
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
fetch: http://nodejs.org/dist/v5.1.1/node-v5.1.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /usr/local/Cellar/nodebrew/0.9.2/bin/nodebrew/src/v5.1.1/node-   v5.1.1-d
Warning: arwin-x64.tar.gz: Not a directory

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 987)
download faild: http://nodejs.org/dist/v5.1.1/node-v5.1.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz
```

I've tried searching for info about the same problem but no luck. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It is the permissions problem. so failed to create directory.

```
 mkdir -p ~/.nodebrew/src
```

Comment: Worked for me on 10.12.5.